vsCode Dart Analysis Server client: couldn't create connection to server
Below is the error message:
I am receiving a warning that VS Code can't connect to the Dart Analysis Server, and the results are as shown in the image below.

Trying:
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Dart, Flutter extensions and delete .dart_tool, ~/.dartServer folder, but it didn't help.

try these steps :-

check the flutter is installed successfully (Flutter Doctor).
update Vscode and flutter sdk.
Run Dart Analysis Server in a Separate Terminal. open the terminal and past this command
dart --enable-asserts --observe --pause-isolates-on-exceptions=always --no-sound-null-safety /path/to/your/project/lib/main.dart

if any of these steps not worked please send the ss of go to output (when the error occure their is a blue box)

Output:
[Error - 7:43:47 PM] Server initialization failed.   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed   Code: -32097  [Info  - 7:43:47 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart. true [Error - 7:43:47 PM] Dart Analysis Server client: couldn't create connection to server.   Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed   Code: -32097 
